# how to change image source to address on disk in runtime wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf

This link answers how to change image source in run-time but it's not work with addresses from disk like below:

```
recivedPic.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\Users\ali\Desktop\Rubik-SMS\Rubik-SMS\Rubik-SMS\Images\Back.jpg" , UriKind.Relative));
```

Only work with addresses like below(pictures belong to project):

```
recivedPic.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Images\Back.jpg" , UriKind.Relative));
```

I need the first one but nothing shows, any suggestion?

Comment: The first one is not a relative UriKind.  I don't recall the options, but try a different one, maybe Absolute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need use `BitmapImage` with uri only. Absolute path isn't a relative so you cant use `UriKind.Relative`.

> Absolute URIs are characterized by a complete reference to the
>   resource (example: http://www.contoso.com/index.html), while a
>   relative Uri depends on a previously defined base URI (example:
>   /index.html).

```
this.yourImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("c:\\img.jpg"));
```

or

```
img.BeginInit();
img.UriSource = new Uri("d:\\img.jpg");
img.EndInit();
this.image1.Source = img;
```

Comment: thank you, that was helpful, i must improve my English first lol